# I really didnt understood the models in dart/flutter or in any language

Tags: flutter, dart, model

Hello I am a flutter dev, I am creating a weather app with flutter, and it been a good experience but one thing I don't understand in any tutorial is that I mean why we should create a model class, e.g:- we create a TODO model in todo app or consider my app like I didn't create models but I am fine with that, you can see the code below I am using to get data from API and to set it to variables without using model classes, can someone please explain to me like you are explaining to a kid, and also give me some example or some great tutorial links, thank you.

Comment: Creating model class helps you avoid mess, that's one benefit that I have experienced.

Comment: yeah but i really get confused, is this part of some pattern

Comment: Sometimes we are wanting to do things "fast and easy" way, but we have to car about he scalability and collaboration, here models come into picture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are tons of benefits from models, in every language, I won't dump a ton of theory to prove that, i will simply post a few **basic** examples, when things get complicated it's simply impossible to maintain a project without using models.

Let's say you're using Maps and Lists to handle data in dart, and for a simple example, in your case for a weather app let's say you get the temperature for a region that is composed from 3 locations. For these locations you get a name and a temperature, and the unit for that temperature.
So the JSON will be something like this:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Location 1",
    "temperature": 23.1,
    "unit": "C"
  },
  {
    "name": "Location 1",
    "temperature": 23.1,
    "unit": "C"
  },
  {
    "name": "Location 1",
    "temperature": 23.1,
    "unit": "C"
  }
]
```

Now let's say you want to write a function that will compute the average temperature of that region. How will you do that, if you don't use any models you'll have probably:

```
double avgTemp(List<String, dynamic>> theRegions) {
   double sumTemp = 0
   theRegions.forEach((element) { 
      sum += element["temperature"] as double; //this is already dangerous
    });
   return sumTemp / theRegions.length;
}
```

So far no problems, but let's say after 1 moth of working on other parts of the app you have to compute the average temperature for a region, that has 3 locations, but this time, the user provides the name, temperature, and unit. I know it's hard to imagine that developers forget what they write a month ago but it happens, and while you know that you have the `avgTemp` function, and while you hardly code you create the maps for the user input and by mistake you make a typo in one of the map, you'll write `tempeature`. I promise you'll speed at least 2 hours trying to figure out why in the hell the average is wrong. Even worse, you won't notice in the beginning.

Now if you had a model called `Location` with a cool constructor that takes 3 params, it would be impossible for you to make a typo there.

Another safety issue here: maps/arrays are mutable in general, and in some cases you can pass them by reference, imagine having to debug a huge chunk of code to see where did the "temperature" changed from 23.1 to 23.2. With models, you can make them immutable and you can easily find where the problem is.

Another reason, speed of changing the implementation, for this exact case, let's say that the key for temperature is changed to `temp` now you'll have to search everywhere in the code and make sure that you update to the new key. Some would argue that you could make a static variable with the name of the key, and yes that would make things easier but i give you another example, instead of a key change what about a json structure change, now the API will return

```
[
  {
    "name": "Location 1",
    "temperature": {
      "value": 23.1,
      "unit": "C"
    }
  }
]
```

In this case, you'll punch the desk and start praying, but if you would use a model to deserialize the json, then you'll had to change it in only one place.

The list can continue indefinitely, and I think everybody on SO would find a different reason why you should use models.

Answer (score 2):

The idea is to improve the separation of concerns by working with layers.

You will see that a lot of Flutter projects work with the following layers:

- Domain
- Application
- Presentation
- Infrastructure

What you call Models are the Entities inside your Domain Layer where you code the Business Logic of your application regardless of other concerns such as the UI (Presentation layer) or persistence (Infrastructure layer).

Have a look at:

- [Reso Coder Flutter TDD Clean Architecture Course](https://resocoder.com/2019/08/27/flutter-tdd-clean-architecture-course-1-explanation-project-structure/)
- [Uncle Bob Clean Architecture](https://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2012/08/13/the-clean-architecture.html)

Comment: Once you start to write tests and you start being angry that the code for your data structures is inside the only widget that needed it (or worse, cut-n-pasted into three!), you'll want some sort of advice about how to be able to understand and test your code better.